# Javascript function does not fire in Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox

I am facing a weird issue in Firefox: I use javascript to open a pop-up when the user clicks some text and it seems that my Javascript function does not fire at all. It works perfectly in IE, Chrome and Opera, but in Firefox nothing happens. I deleted the cache, and still I cannot figure it out why I get no response. Even more no error is thrown. How can I debug this code using Firebug? Any possible ideas why it behaves like this?
Many thanks!

Comment: how can we debug the code without ever seeing it?

Comment: Maybe you should add the code so we can help you out... Nonetheless, you can execute javascript in your firebug console to test parts of your code or all of it

Comment: Could you please post some js/html code? I had similar problem once and it was related with html attributes of the element on whitch I was performing an operation; but I'm not able to tell if it's the same util I look into your code

Comment: you can do with debugger also by just putting the keyword after firebug addon added

Comment: can u create a link pls.....

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial. I hope it's helpful: [debug-javascript-with-firebug](http://thecodecentral.com/2007/08/01/debug-javascript-with-firebug)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes you can debug the code with the FireFox add-on [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/).  The console under Firebug will more than likely tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all the answers. Finally I figured it out why it was behaving weird. I was trying to open the popup at mouse click coordinates and it seems that Firefox has no ideea about window.event.x and window.event.y, I had to use event.clientX and event.clientY instead. 
Unfortunately these were passed as parameters for my javascript function.